# Joining 4 tables with left outer joins and inner join in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

[image]LINQPad Screenshot where TAanlysis is T2 table which I can expand to see details.

I have four tables. Three of them need to join with left while two of them with inner join.

Here is the SQL code that I'm trying to re-code within LINQ:

```
select t1.*,t2.*,t3.*
from t1
left outer join t2 on t1.column1=t2.column1
left outer join t3 on t2.column1=t3.column1
INNER join t4 on t2.column1=t4.column1
where t3.column2=x**
```

**Can anyone help how to write such query in LINQ?**

I tried below LINQ query in .NET which is yielding different SQL query at backend:

```
from prsn in db.T1
join co in db.T2 on prsn.Id equals co.Id into ps1
from y1 in ps1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join tproject in db.T3 on y1.Id equals prod.Id into ps2
from y2 in ps2.DefaultIfEmpty()
join res in db.T4 on y1.Id equals res.Id
where y2.ID == x 
select prsn;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

SQL query formed at backend:

```
select filter1.*
from (Select t1.* from t1 inner join t2 on t1.Id=t2.Id
      left outer join t3 on t2.Id = t3.Id)as filter1
inner join t4 on filter1.Id= t4.Id
where filter1.Id= x
```

I tried above LINQ query in .NET which is yielding different SQL query at the backend. Let me know if I am missing anything?

Note : selection of all columns from 3 tables.

Comment: Did you already try something?

Comment: In general you can't expect one-to-one LINQ query to SQL query translation. The question is are you getting the expected results? Btw, the SQL query looks strange - the way it's written, I think the `INNER JOIN` will effectively turn the first `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER`, and the `WHERE` condition will do the same with the second `LEFT JOIN`, so the result will be like if the all the joins were `INNER`.

Comment: @IvanStoev is correct, you need to address the issues in your SQL before asking for help converting it to LINQ. As is stands all of your joins are implicitly INNER joins.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for your comments. Above Sql query gave me the desired results (Where as table1 and table2 are foreign key linked ,table1 and table3 are foreign key linked).when executing above linq query gave me results with virtual collection of table2 and table3 as 'null'  and other details of table1. If I get the virtual collection of table2 and table3 data it works for me.

Comment: Hmm, are you asking how to return data from multiple join tables? like `select new { prsn, y1, y2, res }`

Comment: yes but I don't want to create new anonymous type instead my requirement is return as collection of T1 entity(Each entity should have respective T2 and T3 entity details).

Comment: @IvanStoev And one more information is in LINQPad 4 tool same above linq query gave me results of T2 and T3 as well. But in my application it is giving as 'null'.

Comment: How are you accessing T2/T3 data from in LINQPad and in your application?

Comment: @NetMage I have added the LINQPad screenshot in the description.

Comment: Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: EF is an ORM. You define relations and the *ORM* will generate the joins. If you have to write the joins, something is missing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried different ways but the collection of T1 entity doesn't have T2 and T3 entity details(they are null). Let me know if you know any way?

Comment: @gershon no since you didn't provide any information. Post your entities, table schema and context configuration. What have you tried? Have you checked any tutorials on how to create relations, eg [this one](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)? The Student and Standard classes in the first example are mapped by convention so don't need *any* configuration